# Where is the appropriate place to get help for specific code examples?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

Is there a place on Stack Exchange where I can find code for subjects which are otherwise off-topic for Stack Overflow? Such an example question "[Simple multithreading Delphi example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227704/simple-multithreading-delphi-example)". I'm not saying this question its self is worthy of an acceptable answer anywhere. But let's look at the topic of Multi-threading. Usually, whenever someone asks how to strategically design a thread to fit particular needs, those questions get closed as "too broad" or "off topic". Threads can be a very tricky mess if you don't design them right, and it would be nice if there were a Stack Exchange site for that.

Is there a site which can accommodate for these types of needs?

Comment: The main problem was how the question was asked - if the question was to explain the concept of multi threading in Delphi, and also asked for an example with the answer along with what the questioner already understands, it might _just_ have had a fighting chance to stay open.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean for that particular question to be of any real relevance, but the subject of multithreading rather

Comment: There's a bunch of hits of likely looking hits when you google, several on stackoverflow. I think it helps to show you tried something: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+do+multithreading+in+delphi

Comment: The higher voted ones are from earlier days in Stack Overflow, lately such questions would be closed in a heartbeat. I'm looking for solutions to the "too broad" questions.

Comment: Multithreading in general is a very complex subject, to the point where there have been entire books dedicated to the subject. How can a single question (regardless of language involved) about such a broad topic be answered on any of the SE sites? The guidelines for SO specifically say that if an entire book could be written on the topic, it's not appropriate for SO. None of the SE sites are for extensive, multi-chapter articles.

Comment: We already have a site for software design questions: [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I actually considered proposing a site for Multithreading, but decided not to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SX sites (SO in that example) are for helping you solve a specific problem. People are here to help you when you stuck at a specific problem.

Beside that, nobody in here is psychic, or spend a lot of time to `try` understand your problem and offer each solution for each possibilities. Or tell you how to do a job from scratch; books and learning is for that, not SO or any other programming based SX site.

Also, asking *which is better* type of questions are mess since there are a lot of ways and each have some pros and cons and the argument keep going without end. Because there is no end since there is no **specific** point in the question.

So if you focus your question. In deed, there is one:  [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

You can write your code and ask for improvement and possible cave-ats and bottle-necks in there.

So it all focuses at one point: Be specific for your question and try to offer a solution so people can offer you advices and corrections. But do not try to make somebody else do your job for you  in here.